# Rust struct can't replace trait in HashMap

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I'm trying to create a `HashMap` containing a known value for a specific input. This input can accept multiple types, as long as they implement a certain trait. In this case, however, only a certain type is given, which Rust doesn't like.

Is there any way to "convert" a struct into a trait, or otherwise fix this issue?

```
#![allow(unused)]

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::*;


trait Element: Eq + PartialEq + Hash {}

trait Reaction<T: Element> {}


#[derive(Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct Ion {
    charge: u16
}

impl Element for Ion {}


#[derive(Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct RedoxReaction<T: Element> { left: T }

impl<T: Element> Reaction<T> for RedoxReaction<T> {}


fn get_sep_database<T: Element>() -> HashMap<RedoxReaction<T>, f32> {
    let mut map: HashMap<RedoxReaction<T>, f32> = HashMap::new();

    let reaction = RedoxReaction {
        left: Ion {
            charge: 1
        }
    };

    // note: expected type `RedoxReaction<T>`
    //       found type `RedoxReaction<Ion>`
    map.insert(reaction, 0.000 as f32);

    return map;
}


fn main() {
    let db = get_sep_database();

    let reaction = RedoxReaction {
        left: Ion {
            charge: 1
        }
    };

    // expected this to be 0.000
    let sep = db.get(&reaction);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution to this problem would be to use *trait objects* instead of generics. Specifically, `RedoxReaction` would be defined as:

```
#[derive(Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct RedoxReaction { left: Box<Element> }
```

However, that doesn't work here because neither `PartialEq`, `Eq` nor `Hash` are [*object safe*](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/). Indeed, it doesn't make a lot of sense to ask if two `Elements` are equal when one of them is an `Ion` and the other is a `Photon`.

I would instead recommend that you consider using an [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html) for your elements. All your elements would have the same type (the enum `Element`), and object safety would not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as you might guess, I'd also like to create new `Element`s (`Molecule`s in this case) at runtime. I'm not sure if (and how) that is possible with enums. For now, I'll see how I can change my code.

Comment: See it like this: for each struct that would have implemented the `Element`  trait, you instead add a variant to the `Element` enum. You can't create types at runtime in Rust, and neither can you create enum variants at runtime, so using an enum instead of a family of types shouldn't hinder you in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved this problem by using the *hash* of the `Reaction` as the key of the `HashMap` with the following function:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::*;

fn reaction_to_hash<E: Element>(reaction: &Reaction<E>) -> u64 {
    let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
    reaction.hash(&mut s);
    s.finish()
}
```

Then you can use `map.insert(reaction_to_hash(&reaction), <value>)` to store the values, and `map.get(& reaction_to_hash(&reaction))` to retrieve the value.